# Change array size by just adding element and no push javascript

Tags: javascript

I know the universal way of changing an array's size is to use `.push()`.

However, today I saw a piece of code in angularJS that does something like this:

```
var service = {
   pages: [],
   doSmth: doSmth
};

doSmth();

function doSmth() {
   service.pages[1] = "abc";
   service.pages[5] = "def";
}
```

I ran the debugger on the browser and found that before `doSmth()` is called, `pages[1]` is undefined, but after that, `pages[1]` is assigned the value without any error.

How is this possible?

Comment: Because pages already been initialized in pages: [] . Without pages:[], you would see the undefined error.

Comment: Assigning values to indices at or past an array’s length will resize it to fit.

Comment: What behaviour did you expect? remember that `function doSmth` is hoisted

Comment: The code actually doesnt work, but, as mentioned, assigning values to indices resizes an array to fit, adding undefined elements to fill the gaps.

Comment: Well like in other languages you would have to do something like var array = new string[10]; or something like that, and I thought pages[] only creates and empty array, and doSmth() would cause and indexOutOfBound

Comment: You can always just add an element to an array at any index and it will "resize" (in so far as the length will appear to be the largest index + 1) to fit. The `push` function is just a convenience to add an element to `myarray[myarray.length]`

Comment: @PTN: There are no OutOfBounds in Javascript.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's just the magic that JavaScript allows. If you come from a language like Java or C, this may seem like a weird idea, but you can set the value of any index in the array at any time, and the array will expand to that size!

Consider:

```
var t = [];
t.length === 0;
t[10000] = 'value';
t.length === 10001;
```

JavaScript just handles this behind the scenes. It's worth mentioning that this behavior is not specific to JavaScript. This is seen a bit in other interpreted languages as well. Ruby, for example, allows you to do the same.

Additionally in JavaScript, `length` is a writeable attribute of arrays, so you can easily truncate or clear an entire array:

```
var t = [1];
t[4] = 0;
t === [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, 0];
t.length = 2;
t === [1, undefined];
t.length = 0;
t === [];
```

Setting the length to 0 is one of the fastest and simplest ways to clear an array. It might not be the most intuitive solution, but it's my go-to.

Comment: Note: The array may not *actually* expand. It will behave as if it did, but internally, depending on the implementation, it may well not have actually assigned any extra space.

Comment: And all this is formally described in specification http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.1

Answer (score 3):

An array in JavaScript is just an object with some special properties.  Essentially, they are just objects with positive, integer property names.  There are some other key differences, but the idea is that you could do this:

```
var obj = { };
obj['1'] = 'abc';
```

So you can do the same with an array.

However!  You shouldn't.  Modern JavaScript engines usually optimize arrays by backing them with fast, native implementations.  By setting indexes that are not currently allocated will de-optimize your code into something more like an object, which is much slower.

Comment: but this is not what is happening

Comment: var obj = { }; <- you are initializing an object, not array. obj = [] is array.

Comment: @CodeiSir: In what way?

Comment: @minitech see my answer, its not the same namespace

Comment: @tanjir, I understand, Array's are just specialized JS Objects.  I was showing the basic way of how you can set any property on an object.  I like Brennans anwer best for explaining the extra magic.

Answer (score 0):

Pages in `function doSmth()` is not in the same namespace as pages in `service`, wich is `service.pages`.

Your `pages[1]` musst be a global declared somewhere else.

However you are initializing `pages` as an empty (but existing) array: `pages: [],`

```
var service = {
    pages: [],
    doSmth: doSmth
};

doSmth();

function doSmth() {
    pages[1] = "abc";
    pages[5] = "def";
}
```