# Why index gets automatically created in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, associative-array

If I try to create an associative array using digit as property, it's inserting other values automatically with null values.

I tried passing a string (myArray['myProp']), array length is zero that time. It is happening only if I pass digits, no matter in string form.

```js
const myArray = [];
myArray[5] = 'My value'; // say index is 5 here
console.log(myArray.length);
```

I want to know what is the logic behind this.

Comment: what is your expectation ?

Comment: Why aren’t you using an object instead of an array?

Comment: length of myArray should be '1' here...

Comment: @Mark Meyer, I can do that but want to know why this happens. Any documentation reference will be great...

Comment: That is the default behaviour of array. what do you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change array size by just adding element and no push javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903514/change-array-size-by-just-adding-element-and-no-push-javascript)

Comment: [Reference 1](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch18.html#array_length)
[Reference 2](https://dmitripavlutin.com/the-magic-behind-array-length-property/)
The basic function of the length property is to track the highest index in an array

Comment: @adiga, LucasNesk, thank you for the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myArray[5]` will try to look into the 5th index , but it cannot skip `0-4`, for that case they will be filled with `undefined`. You can use `Object.values` which give anything except `undefined` and check the length of that

```js
const myArray = [];
myArray[5] = 'My value'; // say index is 5 here
console.log(myArray);
// get everything except undefined
let newArr = Object.values(myArray)
console.log(newArr.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for this... but it should not happen if we pass like this myArray["5"] :)

Comment: 0-4 indexes will be holes, not `undefined` (It shows `undefined` in Stack snippet though)

Comment: @adiga, you are right,but defining holes & visually interpret it is bit challenging

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are storing a value to index 5 in your array.

An object will most likely do the trick?

```
const obj = {};
obj["5"] = "My value";
// { "5": "My value" }
```

Or maybe Map?

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(5, 'My value');
console.log(myMap.size;) // 1
```

Comment: same thing happens if I do like this... const index = '5'; myArray[index] = 'My value';

Comment: You are initialising myArray with a [] which means that it creates an array data type and not an object.

Comment: data type of array in javascript is object.

Comment: @Paveloosha the behaviour is not the same. If you want a length property in array that returns only the real amount of elements, you need to do it by yourself. Try to iterate the elements and check if it is undefined or not.