# Why does adding values in JavaScript extends array length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What happens in the following code for me to get 101?

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];

myArray[100] = "beauty"

console.log(myArray.length);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change array size by just adding element and no push javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903514/change-array-size-by-just-adding-element-and-no-push-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript arrays are zero-based, so

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
```

Has a length of three but the array element indices are 0, 1, and 2.

When you manually insert

```
myArray[100] = "beauty"
```

You put an element in the array with index 100 and then have elements 0-100 inclusive, so 101 array elements.

Comment: Thanks I think i get it. 99 + 0+ 1+1

Comment: @jessi. Correct. 0-100 is 101 items. Like 0-10 is 11 items